# Sub navigation pushing up in IE9

Tags: css, navigation, internet-explorer-9

I am having a problem with the way my horizontal sub navigation in IE9.

This page the navigation renders great in all the rest of browsers but in IE9 it ignores the style given to the list items and pushes the subnav up against the top nav.

Here is the link to the page  I am working on:
http://test.shared-vision.net/menu_test.html

and here is the link to the css"
test.shared-vision.net/css/menuestyle.css

Any sugggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your rule `#menu li.selected ul` you need to set a `bottom` value:

```
#menu li.selected ul {
    bottom: -40px; /* this will make it appear in the right place */
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 150%;
}
```